# Django cache. ManifestStaticFilesStorage

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, caching

I have just started to use ManifestStaticFilesStorage and I am running into a problem I do not understand.

Firstly, if I prepare and run the website without ManifestStaticFilesStorage, then everything displays properly.   Within the browser I can for example, see a link to an image and if I follow that it shows the image in a resource box:

[image]

[image]

Next, I add the following line of code into settings

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and I also have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

I then delete the static directory and rebuild everything (migrations, collect static).

This produces a website with the following link to an image, but the resource is not visible:

[image]

[image]

However, when I go into the static folder in my project and look at the directory, I can see the file clearly and as far as I can tell, it appears normal:

[image]

It's like Django is failing to link up correctly when I use ManifestStaticFilesStorage.

I have included some other settings that may be relevant:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    './ebdjango/static/',
]
```

I'm new to this, so if you have any suggestions on how to proceed with the cache in Django, please let me know.

Many thanks

Mark

Comment: Just an extra bit - I am NOT running it in Debug mode.

Comment: And your web server (nginx or apache) is correctly configured to fetch the location /static/ from the right folder?

Comment: Everything you show here is correct. But you're not explaining how you're serving your static files. I've written a [blog post](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1) on how to do this correctly.

Comment: Hi dirkgroten, thanks for the link.   I will take a look at it and see what I can do.   Currently I am just running the website in using "python manage.py runserver".   I haven't put it onto the server yet, because it doesn't work.

Comment: Django **does not serve static files in production** (DEBUG=False) mode. So it's not surprising that you see nothing loaded. If you go to part 2 of my blog post, you'll see that you can still serve the files with django-whitenoise (but the purpose is really to do that via a CDN) so you could try that first if you really want to try without a web server.

Comment: ok, thank's for that.   I am now getting a bit confused, so I am going to add an answer to my own question, to try to explain why I am confused and what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @MarkyMark1000 was you able to resolve that issue?

Comment: Hi Alex, I must admit that it has been quite a while since I looked at this.   I tend to use something called whitenoise, which I have managed to get to work, so this might not be relevant anymore.